# UIPickerView to display different WebViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, uipickerview

I tried to control my UIWebView with a UIPickerView, in order to display different PDF files. But somehow my code doesn't. Either it crashes if I select a certain row or it displays the wrong PDF. Any ideas?

```
#import "PickerViewTutorialViewController.h"

@implementation PickerViewTutorialViewController

@synthesize pickerView;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self populateArray1];
    [self populateArray2];
}

- (void)populateArray1 {
    array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array1 addObject:@"1"];
    [array1 addObject:@"2"];
    [array1 addObject:@"3"];
    [array1 addObject:@"4"];
    [array1 addObject:@"5"];
    [array1 addObject:@"6"];
}
- (void)populateArray2 {
    array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array2 addObject:@"A"];
    [array2 addObject:@"B"];
    [array2 addObject:@"C"];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark picker view methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 2;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"1"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_1A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_1B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_1C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"2"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_2A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_2B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_2C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"3"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_3A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_3B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_3C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"4"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_4A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_4B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_4C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"5"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_5A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_5B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_5C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"6"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_6A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_6B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_6C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    if (component == 0) {
        return [array1 count];
    }
    else {
        return [array2 count];
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    if (component == 0) {
        return [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else {
        return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you can replace all of the code:

```
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"1"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_1A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_1B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_1C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"2"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_2A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_2B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_2C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"3"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_3A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_3B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_3C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"4"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_4A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_4B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_4C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"5"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_5A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_5B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_5C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
    if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"6"]) {
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"A"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_6A.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"B"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_6B.pdf"]]]]; }
        if ([[array2 objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"C"]) {
            stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Stundenplan_6C.pdf"]]]]; }
    }
```

By:

```
NSString *numberString = [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *letterString = [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *pathComponentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stundenplan_%@%@.pdf", numberString, letterString];
stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponentString]]]];
```

In the first two lines (of the simplified code), you see the problem: When row is 3 or greater, you can't call `[array2 objectAtIndex:row];` which has a length of only 3.

Edit

You can use the method:

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

To determine the correct indices of the letters and numbers:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *numberString = [array1 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    NSString *letterString = [array2 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
    NSString *pathComponentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stundenplan_%@%@.pdf", numberString, letterString];
    stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [stundenplan loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponentString]]]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, but still doesn't solve my main problem. I know where the problem is but I don't know how to make it working...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code crashes, because of how you handle the row selection.
Your second array of objects (array2) has just 3 objects (with indexes 0,1,2), but if you select for example the 4th object in the first component you will try to access object at index 3 in array2 so you will get an "out of bounds" exception.

I would advise you to rewrite your logic in this method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

You should use the `inComponent:(NSInteger)component` part of it to optimize your code

I hope this helps.

Comment: Which means this code only can show "1A", "2B" and "3B". Also, there is no reason for you to have 18 lines with `stundenplan.scalesPageToFit = YES;`. It is enough with only one line, i.e. in the top of your method.

Comment: You could have just said that you want someone to write the whole thing for you.